# room: How to get callback on Room transaction success/failure in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room persistent lib for my Android App with Kotlin. There are few cases where I would like to get a callback when room finishes the transaction. Yes, we can use LiveData and I am already using it but there are few rare cases where we app does not want to observe for changes but get a one-time callback to process ahead.
For example, I am using the following setup:

```
fun insertNewData(oldList: List<String>, finalList: List<String>, callback: () -> Unit) {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        async {
            //1. Call function to delete old relations
            // Delete query on JoinTable

            //2.Call function to get IDs for new data
            // Select or insert query on TableOne

            //3. Call function to assign new relations
            // Insert query on JoinTable
        }.await()

        callback()
    }
}
```

So is this a good setup or there are better ways in Kotlin?
In the above function, I am passing a lambda function to get a callback instead of observing for changes using LiveData.

Comment: In general you can override `RoomDatabase.endTransaction()`. Not sure if that would help you.

Comment: @Uli As room library is a nice wrapper around SQLite, we do not need to call begin...() or end...() manually. Is this the only way? If yes, how would you do that globally for all transactions which should also notify us which transaction is just finished inside `endTransation()`?

Comment: The override would take effect for all transactions using that specific RoomDatabase subclass, there's nothing special you have to do, whether you use the convenience transaction wrapper methods or not. (They call the base transaction methods.) You might look at the source to understand better how all this works. Determining which tables/records were accessed in the transaction would be trickier. InvalidationTracker uses an ingenious approach that you could potentially replicate for your use case, but you may find it too complex. Find a shortcut specific to your use case, like setting flags.

Comment: @Uli Thanks for pointing me at InvalidationTracker. I would have a deep look into it and see if it is suitable for me.

Comment: InvalidationTracker may be all you need, I guess.